# Confusion about the application of Hahn-Banach extension Theorem in a duality argument

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, duality-theorems, dual-spaces, hahn-banach-theorem

in my notes I have the following discussion.

> Let $V \subset H$ two Hilbert spaces, with $V$ continuously embedded in $H$ and let us identify $H$ with its dual space. Then, for $f \in H$, we write $\tilde{f}$ for the Hahn-Banach extension of $f$ to $V'$
> $$<\tilde{f}, v> = (f,v)_{H} \quad  \forall v \in V \quad (\star)$$

### I cannot understand two things:

1. How is it possible to extend an element of $H$ to $V'$? I mean, since $f \in H=H'$ I can apply Hahn-Banach, but I really cannot see why I can extend to $V'$, since $V \subset H$.
2. How is that definition $(\star)$ linked to the fact that $\tilde{f}$ is the extension of $f$ to $V'$?
   From that definition I can only say that the map
   $\tilde{f}: V \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that $v \mapsto  <\tilde{f},v>  = (f,v)_H$ is continuous and hence $\tilde{f} \in V'$

Comment: $f \to (f,v)_H$ is a continuous linear functional on $V$. You can call it $\overline f$.  There is no need for Hahn Banach Theorem.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Do you mean $f \to (f,v)_H$ or $v \to (f,v)_H$? The latter is a linear and continuous functional on $V$, since $|(f,v)_H| \leq ||f||_H ||v||_H \leq ||f||_{H} ||v||_V$.

Comment: Yes, I made a typo. I meant $v \to (f,v)_H$

Comment: Can say that, given $f \in H$, $\tilde{f}: v \mapsto (f,v)_H$ is an extension of $f$ to $V'$? @KaviRamaMurthy This is my crucial point